# Delegate - Method Name Expected Error

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm writing a console calculator on c#. I need the following code start working:

```
Dictionary<string, Delegate> functions = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();

private void AddMyFunction (Delegate d, string name)
{
    if (name == null)
    {
        name = d.Method.Name;
    }
    functions.Add (name, d);
}

public void AddFunction (Func<decimal, decimal> f, string name)
{
    AddMyFunction (f, name);
}

public void AddFunction (Func<decimal, decimal, decimal> f, string name)
{
    AddMyFunction (f, name);
}        

public double PerformOperation (string op, decimal x)
{
    return functions [ op ] (x);
}
```

In the function "PerformOperation" the error: "Method name expected" comes out. Please help someone.

Comment: how is your Delegate declared. ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
public decimal PerformOperation (string op, decimal x)
{
    return (decimal)(functions[op].DynamicInvoke(x));
}
```

And it will work. However, I'd recommend something a little more strongly typed. Perhaps keep multiple dictionaries, one for each delegate type, like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Func<decimal, decimal>> func1;
Dictionary<string, Func<decimal, decimal, decimal>> func2;

public void AddFunction (Func<decimal, decimal> f, string name)
{
    func1.Add(name, f);
}

public void AddFunction (Func<decimal, decimal, decimal> f, string name)
{
    func2.Add(name, f);
} 

public decimal PerformOperation (string op, decimal x)
{
    return func1[op](x);
}

public decimal PerformOperation (string op, decimal x, decimal y)
{
    return func2[op](x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're trying to use the bare `Delegate` type as if it were a *specific* delegate type. If you change your dictionary to:

```
Dictionary<string, Func<decimal, double>>
```

then that error goes away - but you won't be able to add a `Func<decimal, decimal>` as a value in the dictionary, of course... or a `Func<decimal, decimal, decimal>`.

You *could* use [`Delegate.DynamicInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke.aspx) if you don't want to tie yourself to a specific delegate type - but then you'd *still* have a problem of handling the fact that you're expecting a `double` return value but calling a delegate which returns a `decimal`. You'll get an unboxing error if you just cast the result of `DynamicInvoke` to `double`.

There's also the problem that the delegate you're trying to call may have *two* parameters and you're only supplying one argument.

Basically you need to be more consistent about what you want the values in the dictionary to be.